# How to assign cmake variables in the CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I can use cmake like this:

```
cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/build/python ..
```

How could I write this in my `CMakeLists.txt` so that I could simply run this:

```
cmake ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Include

```
set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE $ENV{HOME}/build/python CACHE FILEPATH "")
```

in your CMakeLists.txt. For more information about the `set` command see the online documentation or run `cmake --help set`.

EDIT: The `CACHE FILEPATH ""` part here is mandatory, as pointed out below.

Comment: In case of `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` variable a part `CACHE STRING ""` is  **required**: internally the name of this variable is passed to `find_program` which distinguish whether the variable is **CACHE** one or not. Option `-D` for `cmake` creates CACHE variable. What is optional, that is documentation string (`""` in your case) and proper type of the CACHE variable (in case of `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` the better variable type is `FILEPATH`, not a `STRING`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks a lot! I didn't know those details. The docstring, however, seems to be mandatory as well. If I leave it out I get the error `set given invalid arguments for CACHE mode`.

Comment: I meant that one needn't to provide *descriptive* documentation string. Passing at least `""` is unavoidable though.